# Setting versionNameSuffix in gradle buildType dynamically

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-type

The main issue is that I would like to add a `versionNameSuffix` to one of my buildTypes depending on the flavor that is being compiled.

I have to flavors, `original` and `free` and one buildtype `beta`.
So I would like to do something like this:

```
beta {
    //...
    versionNameSuffix " [BETA " + betaVersion() + "] "
}
```

And `betaVersion()` should depend on the flavor that is being compiled, it should just return a different integer for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of doing this looking at the gradle `StartParameter()`:

```
def betaVersion() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String  tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

    if(tskReqStr.contains("Free"))
        return 1;
    else if(tskReqStr.contains("Original"))
        return 3;
}
```